# I am needing a menu to appear when clicking my menu button. I Would this be an OnClick function or CSS code? This is for Python with Flask webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am starting out designing a website with Python & Flask.

I have a menu bar in the centre of the page, which when click turns to a cross. Upon opening
I want a menu list to appear.

Do I enter the code in the CSS or the JS section of code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .bar1,
    .bar2,
    .bar3 {
      width: 35px;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: #333;
      margin: 6px 0;
      transition: 0.4s;
      position: relative;
      left: 650px;
      top: 50px;
    }
    
    .change .bar1 {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    }
    
    .change .bar2 {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .change .bar3 {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
      transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below in `html` to toggle as menu . Also improved some `CSS`.

> Use the container with `class= "wantToCenter"` if want to center the menu else you can remove it

> Use decoration according to need . I have shown here is demo only

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var y = document.querySelector(".menu")
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  y.classList.toggle("menuChange");
}
```

```css
.wantToCenter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*left: 0px;*/
  margin-top: 50px;
  /*top: 50px;*/
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: relative;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.menu {
  display: none
}

.menuChange {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="wantToCenter">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="menuItems">Home</div>
      <div class="menuItems">Service</div>
      <div class="menuItems">Work</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```